# How can I install a non real-time kernel in my Debian box?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, gpu, real-time

I setup a box with Debian:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
9.13

# uname -a
Linux orange 4.9.0-15-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.258-1 (2021-03-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And now, I am trying to install CUDA but I am getting the error:

```
-> Performing PREEMPT_RT check.
ERROR: The PREEMPT_RT sanity check failed:

The kernel you are installing for is a PREEMPT_RT kernel!

The NVIDIA driver does not support real-time kernels. If you
are using a stock distribution kernel, please install
a variant of this kernel that does not have the PREEMPT_RT
patch set applied; if this is a custom kernel, please
install a standard Linux kernel.  Then try installing the
NVIDIA kernel module again.
```

For what I read about real-time kernels, I don't need them. So, my question is: **How can I install a non real-time kernel in my Debian box without reinstalling/formatting it?**

The box is a server used only to run simulations (no graphical interface) with access only via SSH. We need CUDA to move some simulations to GPU.

Comment: In the world of proprietary, one should follow the compatibility matrix: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html . Requires Debian 10 and kernel 4.19. You could try a stretch-backports kernel which would be similar to a Debian 10's kernel. Maybe upgrading to Debian 10 is mandatory (to fulfill gcc and libc versions)

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as using `apt search linux-image-*`. To find the kernel you want, and then install it.

At the time of writing, I get this on Debian testing:

```
$ apt search linux-image
linux-image-5.10.0-5-amd64/testing,now 5.10.24-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.10.0-5-cloud-amd64/testing 5.10.24-1 amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-5-rt-amd64/testing 5.10.24-1 amd64
linux-image-amd64/testing,now 5.10.24-1 amd64 [installed]
linux-image-cloud-amd64/testing 5.10.24-1 amd64
linux-image-rt-amd64/testing 5.10.24-1 amd64
```

You probably have `linux-image-rt-amd64` installed.  You'll want `linux-image-amd64`  instead which is the same thing, but without the PREMPT_RT patch.  `linux-image-amd64` is a metapackage which brings in the current version of linux (in this case, `linux-image-5.10.0-5-amd64`)

So basically, just do this:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
```

I think the headers package is used by `nvidia-drivers` during configuration so it's a good idea to get that too.  Next, when you reboot you will have the opportunity to select your kernel in the grub-menu.  Select the one without `-rt` in it.

If you only have ssh-access, then you probably won't have access to the grub boot menu. In that case, you'll may need to set the default before you reboot with `grub-set-default`.  Try rebooting first, there is a chance that the package will have set your default automatically. Take a look at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and look for `menuentry` lines.  These will give you the strings you can pass into `grub-set-default`.  In my case, I'd use:

```
sudo grub-set-default 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-5-amd64'
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I be sure that the kernels don't have the PREEMPT_RT patch installed? My kernel have not the **-rt** on the name but has the PREEMPT_RT patch.

Comment: If you are using the official debian kernels, you only need to look for the `-rt` in the name.  What do you have installed now?

Comment: an official kernel downloaded directly from Debian site. Uname -a returns **Linux orange 4.9.0-15-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.258-1 (2021-03-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux**, withou **-rt**.

Comment: I'm not sure why CUDA is detecting the PREEMPT_RT patch.  Maybe someone else will be able to answer.  Sounds like a false-positive to me.